# How to make math calculations in JMeter's JS223 preprocessor or any other preprocessors

Tags: variables, jmeter, integer

I want to make some basic math operations on JMeter props and/or user variables. How can I do it using pre/post processors? Which to use and how to make calculations? I am rookie programmer - last year I was writing some code in Python, but in Jmeter I am completely lost in scripting.

My example simple script which gets a user variable `"last_number"` of value 1 and after or before each HTTP request I want to increase it by 1 (integer)

```
x = vars.get("last_number");
x = x + 1;
log.info(x)
vars.put("last_number", x);
```

Expected `x = 2`.
What I get is `11`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by two ways:
**1- Use JSR223 Pre/Post Processor:**
vars.get() returns value in string and that is the reason it is getting concatenated.Again, to use calculated value as variable you have to use vars.put(String,String) which takes string argument so you have to convert int to String.
**you have to modify your code like :**

```
int x =(vars.get("last_number")).toInteger();
x = x + 1;
log.info(Integer.toString(x))
vars.put("last_number", Integer.toString(x));
```

**2- Use JMeter's Counter**
   Please find below screenshoot to use Counter in JMeter. You can use count as ref. variable which will get incremented by 1
   [Counter Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Nxy.png)

Thank you !! I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) hence [`vars.get()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-) returns a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

So you need to:

1. Cast the result of  `vars.get("last_number");` to an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)
2. Cast the `x` back to String

Suggested code change:

```
x = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("last_number"));
x = x + 1;
log.info('Result is: ' + x)
vars.put("last_number", String.valueOf(x));
```

More information: [How to Perform Arithmetic Operations on Numeric Variables When Load Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-arithmetic-operations-on-numeric-variables-when-load-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

`vars` save by default type String, used with `+ 1` is translate to concatenation of Strings

You need to explicit convert String to Integer/int. In groovy add `as int`:

```
 x = vars.get("last_number") as int;
```